# Javascript will not wait for JQuery animation to finish before executing next command

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to create a simple 2-D game in Javascript. I'm going to use jQuery to do some  animations.

There will be buttons that a player will use to call various functions (Move up/down/left/right, Attack, Defend, etc).

A movement() function will call a secondary function, animateCharacter(), to handle the movement of an image object on screen.

The problem I'm having is that the next command in the movement() function executes before the animateCharacter() function has finished.

I tried to add a callback function, but that didn't fix the situation. I've tried many other things -- setInterval, setTimeout, .delay, etc. Nothing seems to fix this situation. What am I not doing, or what am I doing wrong?

Here's a simplified example of the problem....

- What I'm expecting to happen is the user hits [Move the Block], the image of a yellow face moves a bit to the right; then the mainContainer turns into "hello", and then turns into "goodbye."
- But what happens instead is: The user hits [Move the Block], the mainContainer immediate says "goodbye", then the animation is never visible, but when the animation finishes, the mainContainer turns into "hello."
- If I comment out the final command, the animation is seen and the mainContainer turns into "hello," as expected; but then I don't get to do the that final line of code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<style>
 #mainContainer {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
 }
 #myObject {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color:blue;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:yellow;
  position:relative;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
 <div id="myObject">:c)</div>
</div>
<script>
 // MOVE THE BLOCK TO THE RIGHT
 function animateCharacter(callbackSent) {
  $("#myObject").animate({left: "+=50"},1500, function () { callbackSent();});
 }
 
 // DO THIS WHEN THE BUTTON IS PUSHED
 function doTask() {
  myCallback = function () { document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "hello"; };
  animateCharacter(myCallback);
        // WORKS FINE IF THIS IS COMMENTED OUT, 
        // BUT I WANT MORE CODE TO EXECUTE
  document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "goodbye"; 
 } 
</script>
<button id="pushMe" onclick="doTask();">Move the Block</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code does what it says. Start an animation, then immediately destroy it with "goodbye". Please specify *when* you want `hello` and `goodbye` to appear.

Comment: Hi. 
I don't want it to immediately destroy it. 
I want to see the animation first, and then after it has finished running, for the mainContainer to be replaced with "goodbye."
The "hello" is just a test to see if the animation runs, and then executes a callback.

Comment: Please, try changing the `function () { callbackSent();}` simply for the callback name, i.e `callbackSent`. If it doesn't work, remove completely this parameter, and add `.queue(callbacksent);` after the `animate` function call.

Comment: Added answer below. You have no delay at the moment. Have also tried to neaten up the code a little using more jQuery as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

Moved `document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "goodbye";` to the setTimeout function, that will execute after Hello is printed in the div.

Your code was executing like:

1. Animate the box with 1500 miliseconds - **Animation starts**
2. Change main content to goodBye without waiting for animation completion - **Right after animation start**
3. Animation got Completed, so change content to Hello - **Animation Completes, though the user never saw it.**

```js
// MOVE THE BLOCK TO THE RIGHT
 function animateCharacter(callbackSent) {
  $("#myObject").animate({left: "+=50"},1500, callbackSent);
 }
 
 // DO THIS WHEN THE BUTTON IS PUSHED
 function doTask() {
  myCallback = function () { document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "hello";
                                  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "goodbye"; },1000);
                                 };
  animateCharacter(myCallback);
        // WORKS FINE IF THIS IS COMMENTED OUT, 
        // BUT I WANT MORE CODE TO EXECUTE
  
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<style>
 #mainContainer {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
 }
 #myObject {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color:blue;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:yellow;
  position:relative;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
 <div id="myObject">:c)</div>
</div>

<button id="pushMe" onclick="doTask();">Move the Block</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Puneet. I see you've got it working. I will see if I can get mine to do the same using this, and let you know.

Comment: @user4501876 No worries :)

Comment: Thanks, Puneet, I got it to animate, and I'm so happy! I was hoping for a different approach, but this is just fine for what I'm doing. I have a nest of functions pointing to one another, so I have to go backward and wrap the each set of subsequent commands in a setTimeout() command. Anyway, it works. Great, thanksso much.

Comment: Ok, done. My first question and accepted answer. :c)
I can't even upvote yet -- not enough "reputation."

Comment: @user4501876 No worries mate. You will get it soon if you use SO regularly :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does what it is told at the moment. You need to introduce a delay before showing goodbye.

```
// MOVE THE BLOCK TO THE RIGHT
function animateCharacter(callbackSent) {
    $("#myObject").animate({
        left: "+=50"
    }, 1500, callbackSent);
}

// DO THIS WHEN THE BUTTON IS PUSHED
function doTask() {
    animateCharacter(function () {
        $("#mainContainer").html("hello");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#mainContainer").html("Goodbye");
        }, 3000);
    });
}

$('#pushMe').click(doTask);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7tucg2s5/1/

### Notes:

- I also used jQuery alternatives to shorten the code.
- I moved your inline `onclick` handler to the jQuery equivalent as that is easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks TBAussie. I will give this a try later today.

Comment: Hey, it's working! And it's so beautiful. Not exactly the solution I wanted, but good enough for now. Thanks again -- my first StackOverflow question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put your "goodbye" message directly in #myContainer because this will destroy #myObject. Add another div to hold the message:

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="myObject">:c)</div>
    <div id="myText"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function doTask() {
    myCallback = function () { document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "hello"; };
    animateCharacter(myCallback);
    // WORKS FINE IF THIS IS COMMENTED OUT, 
    // BUT I WANT MORE CODE TO EXECUTE
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "goodbye";
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/0qkt0v5r/

Comment: Thanks Maurice. I know the example is dumb. At the moment, it's a turn-based game -- you do an action, then all of the other characters do their choice of actions. It is laid out on a grid, using a table -- it is displayed in the mainContainer. I can move the characters logically to new (x,y) positions. And I can redraw the grid so the characters are where they are supposed to be. But I wanted to make it so that each movement is animated, like pieces moving around a chessboard. Then, I want to redraw the whole grid & wait for the next player action. I'm sure there's way better ways to do this.

Comment: Do the refresh in your callback then

Comment: You mean, instead of subsequent function calls of doAnimation(); redrawGameBoard(); -- I should do the animation with the redraw as the callback? Like, doAnimation(redrawGameBoard()); I'll see if that can be made into a solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function animateCharacter() {
  return $("#myObject").animate({
    left: "+=50"
  }, 1500, function() {
        $(this)
        .fadeOut(500)
        .parent()
        .html("<span>hello</span>")
        .find("span")
        .delay(1500, "fx")
        .fadeOut(250, function() {
          $(this).html("Goodbye").fadeIn(250)
        })
  })
}

$("#pushMe").on("click", function() {
  animateCharacter()
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <style>
    #mainContainer {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #myObject {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      color: blue;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="myObject">:c)</div>
  </div>
  <button id="pushMe">Move the Block</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see you put the last line of code as a callback to the animation. It's an interesting solution. I will have to figure out how to integrate it. Thanks for the tip.